# ERROR in src/app/app-routing.module.ts(17,1): error TS1005: ',' expected

Tags: angular6

This is my app-routing.module.ts file where I'm getting error while compiling. Please suggest how to fix this. No ',' is missing anywhere.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { PostListComponent } from './posts/post-list/post-list.component';
import { PostCreateComponent } from './posts/post-create/post-create.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: PostListComponent},
  { path: 'create', component: PostCreateComponent},
  { path: 'edit/:postId', component: PostCreateComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
}
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: You're missing a closing Parenthesis.

Comment: parenthesis on end of @NgModule

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing parenthesis for @NgModule

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})   // <--- Missing parenthesis here!
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, was unnecessarily looking for the ',' as per the error.